# Find relationship between parameters to prove conditions of eigenvalues

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, polynomials, eigenvalues

I have the following 3-by-3 matrix. I need to find condition(s) on the parameters 'a' and 'b' such that this matrix has exactly 1 eigenvalue bigger than 1 in absolute value and other two eigenvalues less than 1 in absolute value. 'a' and 'b' lie in the range 0 to 3 and I am keen to arrive at an anlaytical expression for these conditions.

```
m = {{14.6235 (0.0925809 + 0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.256263 b)), -14.6235 (0.0240451 + 0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.264 b)), 0.435909}, {1, 0, 0}, {a + 3.68018 b, -a - 3.79129 b, 0}}
```

I would really appreciate any help with this. Thank you very much.

Comment: I tried using `Reduce` but it is taking too long to finish.  Deleted the answer as I had initial error. But you can try this and wait and see `ClearAll[a,b];
m={{14.6235 *(0.0925809+0.0378381* (0.0696333 *a+0.256263* b)),-14.6235* (0.0240451+0.0378381* (0.0696333 *a+0.264* b)),0.435909},{1,0,0},{a+3.68018* b,-a-3.79129 *b,0}}; m=SetPrecision[m,Infinity]; (*exact is better*) eig=ToRadicals@Eigenvalues[m];` and now ...

Comment: `Reduce[Abs[eig[[1]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[2]]] < 1 && Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1 && 
   0 < a < 3 && 0 < b < 3, {a, b}];
Reduce[Abs[eig[[2]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[1]]] < 1 && Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1 && 
   0 < a < 3 && 0 < b < 3, {a, b}];
Reduce[Abs[eig[[3]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[2]]] < 1 && Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1 && 
   0 < a < 3 && 0 < b < 3, {a, b}];`

Comment: Removing the conditions `0 < a < 3 && 0 < b < 3` from `Reduce` it is still taking long time.  But you can try it. `Reduce[Abs[eig[[1]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[2]]] < 1 && 
   Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1, {a, b}];
Reduce[Abs[eig[[2]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[1]]] < 1 && 
   Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1, {a, b}];
Reduce[Abs[eig[[3]]] > 1 && Abs[eig[[2]]] < 1 && 
   Abs[eig[[3]]] < 1, {a, b}];` May be different approach is needed.

Comment: Doing some random sampling seems to indicate that a necessary & sufficient condition is that $\det(M - I) > 0$, which reduces to the simple condition that `b < 0.0423651` with `a` unconstrained.  But I can't prove it, and I have to call it a day.  I'll try to return to it later.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Nasser

Answer (score 2):

To make the job easier, we shift the eigenvalues by -1. Then the condition reads: **2 eigenvalues <0 and 1 eigenvalue >0**. Shifting the eigenvalues can be achieved by subtracting the Identity matrix:

```
m = {{14.6235 (0.0925809 + 
        0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.256263 b)), -14.6235 (0.0240451 + 
        0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.264 b)), 0.435909}, {1, 0, 
     0}, {a + 3.68018 b, -a - 3.79129 b, 0}} - IdentityMatrix[3];
```

Now we consider the characteristic polynomial, whos zeros are the eigenvalues of m:

```
charpoly = Det[m - x IdentityMatrix[3]]
```

[image]

As you can see this is a cubic polynomial. These can have imaginary roots. To get 3 real roots we need an additional condition: the discriminant has to be positive (note there exists different definitions that require the discriminant to be negative):

```
disc = Discriminant[charpoly, x]
```

Further, you will remember, that the constant term of a polynomial with the coefficient of the highest term equal to 1, is the product of its roots.

```
const = Select[charpoly, FreeQ[#, x] &]
```

Note, for 2 roots <0 and 1 root >0 this product must be positive.

Therefore, we have the conditions:

```
disc>0

const>0
```

The solution to this is a very complicated region. But fortunately we have 2 further conditions: 0<={a,b}<=3. With this we get:

```
Reduce[{disc > 0 && const > 0 && 0 <= a <= b && 0 <= b <= 3}, {a, b}]
```

You will see that `Reduce` produces superfluous output of the form `1.20167 < a < 1.20167...`, I think this is an error. But it boils down to:

```
(*0 <= a < 3 && 0 <= b < 0.0423651*)
```

We may plot the regions:

```
RegionPlot[{disc > 0, const > 0}, {a, 0, 3}, {b, 0, 3}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Or the combined region:

```
RegionPlot[{disc > 0 && const > 0}, {a, -0.3, 3}, {b, 0, 0.05}, 
 PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Doesn't your first step assume that the eigenvalues are all real and positive?  For example, consider the matrix with $-2$, $2$, and $0$ on the diagonal.  It doesn't satisfy the criteria (since two of the eigenvalues have a magnitude greater than 1), but subtracting the identity gives a matrix with one positive and two negative eigenvalues.

Comment: That said, your results are very similar (identical?) to mine, so I suspect your argument could still be fixed.

Comment: Thank you very much, @DanielHuber

Comment: I actually over read "absolute value". What I wrote is for 2 values <1 and one value>1.

Answer (score 2):

We can apply [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem).  This theorem states for for any two polynomials $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ and any region in the complex plane $K$, if $|f(z) - g(z)| < |g(z)|$ at every point on the boundary of $K$, then $f(z)$ and $g(z)$ have the same number of roots (counting multiplicities) in the interior of $K$.

In particular, let's take $K$ to be the unit disc.  The polynomial $g(z) = c z^n$ has $n$ (degenerate) roots at the origin. In particular, let's pick $g(z) = c z^2$.  Then if $|f(z) - c z^2| < |c z^2|$ everywhere on the boundary of the unit disc, there are precisely two roots of $f(z)$ inside the unit disc.  And if
we take $f(z) = \det(M - I z)$ to be the characteristic polynomial of $m$, then the values of $a$ and $b$ for which $f(z)$ has two roots inside the unit disc are those for which precisely one eigenvalue of $M$ has magnitude greater than 1.

#### Implementation:

Define the matrix and the characteristic polynomial $f(x)$.

```
m[{a_, b_}] = {{14.6235 (0.0925809 + 
  0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.256263 b)), -14.6235 (0.0240451 + 
  0.0378381 (0.0696333 a + 0.264 b)), 0.435909}, {1, 0, 0}, {a + 3.68018 b, -a - 3.79129 b, 0}};
f[x_, a_, b_] = CharacteristicPolynomial[m[{a, b}], x]

(* 0. - 0.435909 a - 1.65266 b - 0.351624 x + 0.397379 a x + 
   1.45815 b x + 1.35386 x^2 + 0.0385299 a x^2 + 0.141797 b x^2 - 1. x^3 *)
```

Tell Mathematica to find `a` and `b` such that $|f(z) - c_2 z^2| < |c_2 z^2|$ for all $z$ on the unit circle, where $c_2$ is the coefficient of $z^2$ in $f(z)$.

```
c2 = Coefficient[f[z, a, b], z, 2];
conditions = 
Simplify[Reduce[
   ForAll[z, Abs[z] == 1, Abs[f[z, a, b] - c2 z^2] < Abs[c2 z^2] 
   && 0 <= a <= 3 && 0 <= b <= 3], {a, b}, Reals]];
Chop[conditions]

(* 0 <= a <= 3. && 0 <= b < 0.0423651 *)
```

This appears to be in agreement with "data" from random sampling in the allowed parameter space:

```
points = Select[RandomReal[{0, 3}, {100000, 2}], (Sort[Abs[Eigenvalues[m[#]]]][[3]] >= 1 && Sort[Abs[Eigenvalues[m[#]]]][[2]] < 1) &];
ListPlot[points, PlotRange -> {{0, 3}, {0, 3}}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

#### Caveats:

While the results agree with the "random sampling" data, Rouché's theorem is new to me and I am not 100% sure that I have applied it correctly.  In particular, while it appears to be customary to take $g(z) = c_2 z^2$ in using this technique to find roots, I am not sure why this is or whether it would be possible to use other choices for $c_2$.  In addition, I am unclear whether Rouché's theorem is an "if and only if" statement, or whether it only provides sufficient conditions (but not necessary conditions) for $f(z)$ to have a particular number of zeros in $K$.  I welcome any & all comments on this answer correcting any misconceptions.

Comment: Thank you very much, @MichaelSeifert